# Invoking a constructor in a 'with' statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, with-statement

I have the following code:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        print(f'entering {self.name}')

    def __exit__(self, exctype, excinst, exctb) -> bool:
        print(f'exiting {self.name}')
        return True

with Test('first') as test:
    print(f'in {test.name}')

test = Test('second')
with test:
    print(f'in {test.name}')
```

Running it produces the following output:

```
entering first
exiting first
entering second
in second
exiting second
```

But I expected it to produce:

```
entering first
in first
exiting first
entering second
in second
exiting second
```

Why isn't the code within my first example called?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The `__enter__` method should return the context object. `with ... as ...` uses the return value of `__enter__` to determine what object to give you. Since your `__enter__` returns nothing, it implicitly returns `None`, so `test` is `None`.

```
with Test('first') as test:
    print(f'in {test.name}')

test = Test('second')
with test:
    print(f'in {test.name}')
```

So `test` is none. Then `test.name` is an error. That error gets raised, so `Test('first').__exit__` gets called. `__exit__` returns `True`, which indicates that the error has been handled (essentially, that your `__exit__` is acting like an `except` block), so the code continues after the first `with` block, since you told Python everything was fine.

Consider

```
def __enter__(self):
    print(f'entering {self.name}')
    return self
```

You might also consider not returning `True` from `__exit__` unless you truly intend to unconditionally suppress *all* errors in the block (and fully understand the consequences of suppressing other programmers' errors, as well as `KeyboardInterrupt`, `StopIteration`, and various system signals)

Comment: Interestingly, the original PEP-310 proposal for `with` behaved as the OP expected. This was changed in PEP-343. I wonder why they didn't make the object the default context when `__enter__` returns `None`, since that's such a common case.

Comment: @Barmar: Sometimes `__enter__` returns `None` because the `as` target really should be set to `None`. If a return value of `None` was special-cased, that would break cases where `None` really is desired. Saving a few `return self` lines isn't worth that.

Comment: (And no, I don't mean an `__enter__` method with a plain `return None`. I'm talking about cases like if `__enter__` returns the value of some state variable that's allowed to be `None`, or if it returns the result of some computation whose output could be `None`.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Wouldn't that cause an error when it later tries to call `None.__exit__()`?

Comment: @Barmar: No. `with` calls the context manager's `__exit__`, not the `__enter__` return value's `__exit__`.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that your `__enter__` method returns `None`. Hence, `test` is assigned `None`.

Then you try to access `(None).name`, which raises an error. Since your `__exit__` method returns `True` always, it will suppress any errors. According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager):

> Returning a true value from this method will cause the with statement
> to suppress the exception and continue execution with the statement
> immediately following the with statement.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this behavior is because `__enter__` must return something that will be operated on, that in this case will be accessed with the name `test`. By changing `__enter__` to the following

```
def __enter__(self):
    print(f"entering {self.name}")
    return self
```

we get the expected behavior.

Comment: `__enter__` doesn't *have* to return a value, but `Test` is used in a way that *assumes* it will.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the first and second cases don't do the same.

In `first`:

- the object is created, which calls `__init__`;
- then `with` calls `__enter__`;
- then `as` stores the result of `__enter__` into `test`
- since `__enter__` doesn't have a return value, `test` is `None`.

In `second`:

- the object is created, which calls `__init__`;
- then assigned to `test`;
- then `with` calls `__enter__`;
- but nothing is done with the result of `__enter__`;
- so `test` keeps referring to the object that was created originally.

In both cases, `__exit__` is called for the object that `with` is handling, so you see the right label being printed; it's just that, in `first`, the `test` identifier is not bound to that same object.

NB `__enter__` doesn't have to return `self`. It might return something else entirely, for instance you may open a file and make `__enter__` return the stream, while `__exit__` may close it. If it were a given that `__enter__` should return `self`, that would be redundant and could just be implied.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

`__enter__` is giving `None` as an output, since there is no `return`, therefore it would directly trigger `__exit__` since `None` has no attribute `name`, ex:

```
>>> None.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    None.__name__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
>>>
```

If you set it to call `__class__.__name__` (`None` objects have that attribute, which gives `NoneType`), you could find the problem easily:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        print(f'entering {self.name}')

    def __exit__(self, exctype, excinst, exctb) -> bool:
        print(f'exiting {self.name}')
        return True

with Test('first') as test:
    print(f'in {test.__class__.__name__}')

test = Test('second')
with test:
    print(f'in {test.__class__.__name__}')
```

Output:

```
entering first
in NoneType
exiting first
entering second
in Test
exiting second
```

As you can see, it says `in NoneType`, not returning any value is the reason to this. In a lot of cases, `__enter__` doesn't need to return, but in this case the `Test` class needs it to return.

### Solution:

The solution would be to keep the `Test` instance, so that it calls the `name` of a returned `self` after the context manager `__enter__` result. So far the `__enter__` results `None`, therefore `None.name` attribute doesn't exist. So if you return `self`, `test.name` attribute would exist.

The solution would be to return `self` in the `__enter__` magic method implementation:

```
    ...
    def __enter__(self):
        print(f'entering {self.name}')
        return self
    ...
```

---

Full code:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __enter__(self):
        print(f'entering {self.name}')
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exctype, excinst, exctb) -> bool:
        print(f'exiting {self.name}')
        return True

with Test('first') as test:
    print(f'in {test.name}')

test = Test('second')
with test:
    print(f'in {test.name}')
```

Output:

```
entering first
in first
exiting first
entering second
in second
exiting second
```

The extra info I gave that the other answers didn't give is a more concrete proof of the `__enter__` method implementation giving `None`. I showed an example as well of it.